# How to use IOBuffer with file read in julia1.1.0?

Tags: file, io, julia

I am new to Julia! Excuse me, if the thing is trivial or silly!
I am trying to read file with the following code in readlines.jl:

```
#! /opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/bin/Julia
function readlines(file_path::String)
    io = IOBuffer()
    global file
    try
        file = open(file_path)
        l0 = readline(file)
        for line in eachline(file)
           println(io, line)
        end
    catch err
        println("Error: $err")
    finally
        close(file)
    end
end
readlines("/opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/LICENSE.md")
```

executing, $/home/julia/readlines.jl does not print the content of the file.

Please help me in using IOBuffer in file reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are not returning `io` from a function. Here is a fix with some code cleanup (in particular note that `readlines` function is defined in Base, so it is better to use another function name):

```
function readlines2(file_path::String)
    io = IOBuffer()
    open(file_path) do file
        l0 = readline(file)
        for line in eachline(file)
            println(io, line)
        end
    end
    io
end
```

Now you can run it to get `IOBuffer` as a returned value. Note, that usually you will want to convert the contents of this `IOBuffer` ino a string, you can do it using `take!` and `String` functions like this:

```
io = readlines2("your_file.ext")
str = String(take!(io))
```

Now `str` contains the read-in data as a string.

Finally you might prefer to use an in-built `readlines` function and just drop the first entry of the returned vector and then `join` the remaining values like this:

```
join(readlines("your_file.ext", keep=true)[2:end])
```

to get an identical result (this is probably a bit slower, but it is simpler).